# How can I integrate spring security with an existing web application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web-applications, spring-security

FYI, I'm using Tomcat 5.5.

Simply put, I want to integrate Spring Security into an existing web application.  The web app is proprietary; I have no access to its Java source code.  The name of the web app is [BMC ARS Remedy Mid-Tier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AR_Mid-Tier), and I do have access to the web.xml file, of course.  I'm not looking to build a Spring MVC application.

Is there a tutorial or guide which shows you how to integrate Spring Security with a "black box" web application?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: What are you authenticating your users against?

Comment: The web application has its own authentication system.  I want to wrap it with Spring Security and, ultimately, use the web applications authentication system.

Comment: And you want to intercept those authentication calls or just add yours? Why do you need to add Spring Security to that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I integrate Java Spring Security with BMC Remedy ARS Mid-Tier web app, with SSL for authentication only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355398/how-can-i-integrate-java-spring-security-with-bmc-remedy-ars-mid-tier-web-app-w)

Comment: I want to intercept those authentication calls.  The underlying reason is SSL for authentication only.  But this discussion is just to get the existing web application working with Spring Security.  It's all about baby steps.  If I can, at least, get this web app to work with Spring Security, I can go from there.  Right now, I don't even know if Spring Security is compatible with this web app.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem unless the app is coded to do some out of the norm authentication. If everything is in the web.xml then replacing the current security constraints or whatever with the spring security filter should work just fine. Just treat it like any wepapp.